# Function to list number of leap years in a list of years

Tags: python, list, leap-year

I am not looking for the answer, but I am looking for a pointer in the right direction to figure this out myself.

I have a problem where I have a function to RETURN the number of leap years in a LIST of eight years.  I am uncertain as to how to approach this.  I have tried using a FOR LOOP and have also tried using both the calendar.isleap and calendar.leapdays methods, but I seem to be missing something because I am still getting errors.

--- code follows ---

```
def countLeapYears(yearList):
```

(student code goes here.)

```
print(countLeapYears([2001, 2018, 2020, 2090, 2233, 2176, 2200, 2982]))
print(countLeapYears([2001, 2018, 2020, 2092, 2204, 2176, 2200, 2982]))
```

I have edited and presented the question as my request got flagged On Hold for what looks like not enough information.  So above is the actual question.

What I tried was this:

```
ly = 0
for i in yearList:
    if i % 4 == 0:
        ly += 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi ! This will be better if you show the code you've tried :-) Also, could you please paste the error code directly on text instead of an image ?

Comment: OK... So I edited the question, per the comments on the Hold notice... how long does it usually take to get it released from hold?

Answer (score 1):

Considering your input is a list and not a range between 2 values, you are currently trying to call the wrong function.

I suggest writing your own function that takes a list as its input argument and utilizes the modulo operator within its algorithm: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html

Answer (score 1):

OK... thanks for the few inputs I got.  With some help pushing me in the correct direction, here is what I have.  It works and the answers are what I was supposed to.

```
import calendar

def countLeapYears(yearList):

    j=0
    for i in listYears:
        if calendar.isleap(int(i)):
            j += 1
    return j
```

expected output: 2

> print(countLeapYears([2001, 2018, 2020, 2090, 2233, 2176, 2200,
>   2982]))

expected output: 4

> print(countLeapYears([2001, 2018, 2020, 2092, 2204, 2176, 2200,
>   2982]))

Answer (score 0):

If your just looking for a pointer in the right direction here is the source code for the function your attempting to call.  The doc string would might be helpful :D

```
def leapdays(y1, y2):
    """Return number of leap years in range [y1, y2).
       Assume y1 <= y2."""
    y1 -= 1
    y2 -= 1
    return (y2//4 - y1//4) - (y2//100 - y1//100) + (y2//400 - y1//400)
```

Comment: The actual function name and the required print statements are laid out for me, all I need to do is write the code after the function name.

So, for example, the function appears like this:

def leapyearlist(leapYears):


print(leapyearlist([1999, 2004, 2008, 2149]))

Comment: Your code is failing at the function call point. Two arguments are required you are missing the second one hence the fail message.

Comment: Yeah, see... I am not sure it requires the leapdays.  It may be something else that I am not seeing.   Sorry... not intentionally being vague... Trying to get an idea of what to do without you guys solving it for me.  Don't learn anything that way and I have read enough posts here to see how people get snarked when they post their homework for others to do for them.  :-)